# Locate table cell and get next cell's text with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table, traversal

I have an rgb value(currentColorRGB) and want to locate the cell from a table(#previewColorTable) whose background is the rgb value and then retrieve the text from the cell immediately after it, which is the color's "name".

This is as far as I have gotten, which returns an object:

```
var currentColorRGB = some rgb value;
var tableRow = $("td").filter(function() {
        return $('#previewColorTable').css('background-color') == currentColorRGB;
    }).closest("tr");
```

If it helps here is a snapshot of the table I am trying to get info from:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using this script:

```
var currentColorRGB = some rgb value;
var nexttdText = '';
var tableRow = $("td").each(function() {
    var currentBackground = $(this).css('background-color');
    if (currentBackground == currentColorRGB) {
         nexttdText = $(this).next().html();
         return false;
    }
});
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Get the text from the first table cell.

```
tableRow.find("td").eq(0).text();
```

or

```
tableRow.find("td:eq(0)").text();
```

or

```
tableRow.find("td:first").text();
```

or

```
tableRow.find("td").first().text();
```

or

```
tableRow.find("td:first-child").text();
```

Comment: can you tell me why :`code`var colorName=$(tableRow).find("td").first().text();
   alert(colorName); `code` is not working?

Comment: what does `alert(tableRow.length)` give you?

Comment: ah...there's the problem. It returns zero.